# Is an unbounded function bounded on a bounded non-compact interval?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm a little confused about functions in the set of bounded continuous functions.

For example, if we take the interval (0,1] and the function

$f(x) = $\begin{cases} 
0 & x \in (0,\frac{1}{2}]\\
t + \frac{1}{2} & x \in (\frac{1}{2},1]\\
\end{cases}

Then is this function in the set of bounded continuous functions?

Alternatively, if $f(x)=x^\frac{-1}{2}$ on I=(0,1] then is this function in the set of bounded continuous functions?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Is the first one meant to be $t-1/2$ on the second interval? If not, then it has a discontinuity at 1/2 so it'd be disqualified on those grounds. Second one is continuous on the given set but not bounded (consider the sequence $f(x_n), x_n=1/n^2$, say). It just comes down to checking whether, on the given set, your function is i) bounded and ii) continuous.

Comment: What if the function was f(x)=x on I=[0,1], the function is clearly continuous but is it bounded on I even though it is an unbounded function?

Comment: Yep, because it's bounded on $I$ - you basically forget about what it's doing outside of that set. $\vert f(x) \vert \leq 1$ for $x \in I$, which means it's bounded. It's all defined relative to the interval you're considering.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clarifying!